# What are ATRANS and PTRANS in AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

While studying natural language processing I've come across the subject of Conceptual Dependencies.  I've seen examples like this:

```
   (PTRANS ACTOR(MARY) TO(SCHOOL))
   (ATRANS ACTOR(JOHN) OBJECT(BOOK) TO(MARY))
```

What exactly do these lines mean?  Specifically what are the definition of terms like `PTRANS` and `ATRANS`?

Comment: Where have you stumbled upon them? Weren't they introduced in the texts you've read? Have you searched for them? This question is much to unspecific, so voting to close.

Comment: The first line means that Mary went to school. A physical transfer (ptrans). The second line means John gives a book to Mary, but this doens't mean the book moved. An abstract transfer (atrans). Interesting that the question was closed because a moderator from SE doidn't understand it.

Comment: This was confusing for me too. I ran across this in the Carbonell paper on POLITICS, an early ideological inference engine. The idea was to answer questions about geopolitics from a conservative or liberal point of view: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15516709cog0201_3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ptrans-transfer of the physical location of an object
atrans-transfer of an abstract relationship.
 these words are used for representing  conceptualization.these words represent conceptualization correspond to semantic relations among the underlying concepts.
CD provides informal construct that means you can represent them in one standard, these are not binded to any perticular language.

you can implement CD in prolog or LISP language